# Firebase Crash Reporting automatically generates reports for fatal errors in android phone but not for iPhones?

Tags: crashlytics

I have setup firebase in my react native app.

But currently exceptions are not handled means not added any crashlytics logs or recorded errors

But for android app I am getting crashes in firebase but not for IOS.

Can someone explain this in detail?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are testing while the Xcode debugger is attached.
Check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios#force-test-crash), it explains how to test this in iOS.

If that doesn't work, enable [debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios#enable-debug-logging) and check if something is causing issues. For this:

1. After enabling debug mode, run the app.
2. Then hit "stop" in Xcode.
3. Run the app in the device and crash it
4. Run the app again from Xcode
5. Collect the output from Xcode

Comment: I am testing in release mode but still not finding crashes

Comment: I added some steps on how to obtain debug logs. Follow them and see if the logs show something else. Also, how did you install Crashlytics? What is the version? if you go to the dSYMs tab in the Crashlytics dashboard, do you see any missing dSYMs?

Answer (score 0):

Crashlytics may only be able to upload the data once the app starts again. Did you restart the app?

Comment: Checked this as well still not working